# Why is the hash code of args in main method confined in some sets of values only?

Tags: java, random, program-entry-point, hashcode, args

I have a program which only needs one random number, the random number can be insecure, so I am trying to use the hash code of args as random number because it does not require any additional import statements:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int r=args.hashCode();
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

but after I run 20 times, I found the hash code of args looks not so random:

```
1265744841
745503977
745503977
400535505
1265744841
745503977
745503977
745503977
1265744841
1265744841
745503977
1265744841
1586482837
1265744841
56264551
745503977
745503977
745503977
400535505
1265744841
```

It looks some values appeared repeatedly, and I try to reboot machine and run the program 20 times again, some values still appear repeatedly, and some values are even the same as values before reboot:

```
745503977
745503977
745503977
745503977
745503977
400535505
745503977
745503977
745503977
745503977
745503977
745503977
745503977
1265744841
745503977
745503977
745503977
745503977
745503977
1265744841
```

and even I added some values in args (e.g.:java Test abc), similar sets of values still appear, what is the reason?

Comment: What arguments do you use when you run the program? The hashcode is not random, the same arguments should produce the same hashcode.

Comment: @dunni: The OP is calling `hashCode()` on an array. That doesn't use the content of the array...

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `hashCode()` on an array. Arrays don't override `hashCode()`, `equals()` or `toString()` - so you're getting a result which doesn't depend on the *content* of the array at all, and probably depends on where it happens to be in memory. If you wanted a hash code depending on the values within the array, you could call [`Arrays.hashCode(args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-java.lang.Object:A-) - but then you'd always get the same result for the same input, which isn't your intention.

Now, as for your *purpose*:

> I have a program which only needs one random number, the random number can be insecure, so I am trying to use the hash code of args as random number because it does not require any additional import statements

That's a terrible, terrible reason to decide to use something... and hash codes should *never* be used as random number generators.

If you really, really don't want to add an import statement (and why not?) just use `Random` explicitly:

```
int x = new java.util.Random().nextInt(100); // Or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.Array hashCode method is inherited from Object, which means the hashcode depends on the reference. To get the hashcode based on the content of the array use `

> Arrays.hashCode(int[])

This would returns a hash code based on the contents of the specified array.